# Extensions of Weierstrass Factorization Theorem: Essential Singularities and Branch Points

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know under what conditions I can take an analytic multi-valued complex function of one variable and rewrite it (while restricting it to $\mathbb{C}$) as a product of a meromorphic function and all of its singularities and branch points?  Basically, is there an extension of Weierstrass factorization theorem beyond meromorphic functions that would allow a decomposition to include finite plane essential singularities and branch points?  Additionally, can anyone recommend some good texts to learn about this problem?